# fiddler autoresponder add latency rule not working

Tags: networking, fiddler

Using Fiddler I am trying to use the Autoresponder to add a rule that when I hit my web service url which is as per below:

```
http://uummas09:28020/RestfulRetekService/ItemWebService.json?action=keywordSearch&username=StockOnHandPortlet&sessionId=P_ISomGc6U5_433Vh3ApmwI&keywords=Green&itemStatus=A
```

I want fiddler to add latency of 50000 milliseconds (50 seconds). But I am having troubles getting fiddler to do that for me. Here is how I've tried to set up the rule in fiddler.

[image]

The rule is specified as...

```
EXACT:http://uummas09:28020/RestfulRetekService/ItemWebService.json?action=keywordSearch&username=StockOnHandPortlet&sessionId=P_ISomGc6U5_433Vh3ApmwI&keywords=Green&itemStatus=A
```

My first question is how can I wildcard the url in the rule so that it does not consider the query string?

Also I tried to get a rule to work for me for a simple url. i.e. I set a rule for

```
EXACT:http://www.google.com.au
```

but it still did not work for me. Can someone point me out to what I might be doing wrong.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on @EricLaw's answer, to enable the auto-responder:

- Check **Enable automatic responses** to tell Fiddler that you want to respond to requests.
- Check **Unmatched requests passthrough** to tell Fiddler that you want any requests not matched by your rules.

Your rule won't cause a delay because rules aren't matched when they have a blank action to respond with, so if you only want to add a delay, use the `*delay:1000` as the response, instead of a file path.  You can get the latency to work by typing something like `*action` (which isn't a real action) to get it to match and cause the delay.

Comment: *action is a good trick. Why on earth isn't `Passthrough` an option for the reponses list though

Answer (score 1):

For those who are trying to delay HTTPS traffic, check that you **trust your root certificate** and **capture HTTPS traffic**.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You haven't checked the box at the top-left, **Enable Automatic Responses**, so none of your rules run.

To create a rule that ignores the query string, remove `EXACT:` from the front of the rule and delete everything after the `?`.

Comment: Also, please check the checkbox "Unmatched requests passthrouth".